# How to resize fs_tmp from a raid 0 filesytem

Tags: mdadm

I would like to resize the tmp_fs partition and will need guidance on how to do it. I have a mixture of raid0 and sata.

In fact i would like to resize vg_tmp-tmpfs (actually 9.99 GiB) to at least 50Gib.

How can i do it ??

```
    (base) ➜  ~ cat /proc/mdstat
    Personalities : [raid0] 
    md125 : active raid0 nvme1n1p3[1] nvme0n1p4[0]
          1931186688 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
          
    md126 : active raid0 nvme1n1p2[1] nvme0n1p3[0]
          10475520 blocks super 1.2 256k chunks
          
    md127 : active raid0 nvme1n1p1[1] nvme0n1p2[0]
          10475520 blocks super 1.2 256k chunks
          
    unused devices: <none>
    (base) ➜  ~ 




    (base) ➜  ~ sudo fdisk -l   
    [sudo] password for david: 
    Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
    Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB            
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x98553f50
    
    Device         Boot    Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
    /dev/nvme0n1p1          2048    1128447    1126400  550M 83 Linux
    /dev/nvme0n1p2       1128448   11614207   10485760    5G 83 Linux
    /dev/nvme0n1p3      11614208   22099967   10485760    5G 83 Linux
    /dev/nvme0n1p4      22099968 1953525167 1931425200  921G 83 Linux
    
    
    Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
    Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB            
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x691e3c74
    
    Device         Boot    Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
    /dev/nvme1n1p1          2048   10487807   10485760    5G 83 Linux
    /dev/nvme1n1p2      10487808   20973567   10485760    5G 83 Linux
    /dev/nvme1n1p3      20973568 1952450559 1931476992  921G 83 Linux
    
    
    Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
    Disk model: ST2000DM008-2FR1
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/md127: 9.99 GiB, 10726932480 bytes, 20951040 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 524288 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/md126: 9.99 GiB, 10726932480 bytes, 20951040 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 524288 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/md125: 1.8 TiB, 1977535168512 bytes, 3862373376 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/mapper/vg_main-rootfs: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/mapper/vg_main-homefs: 1.7 TiB, 1870156267520 bytes, 3652648960 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/mapper/vg_tmp-tmpfs: 9.99 GiB, 10724835328 bytes, 20946944 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 524288 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/mapper/vg_swap-swap: 9.99 GiB, 10724835328 bytes, 20946944 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 524288 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/loop0: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/loop1: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    
    
    Disk /dev/mapper/docker-254:1-110757361-pool: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes


 ~ vgs
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vg_main   1   2   0 wz--n- <1.80t    0 
  vg_swap   1   1   0 wz--n- <9.99g    0 
  vg_tmp    1   1   0 wz--n- <9.99g    0 

➜  ~ pvs
  PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/md125 vg_main lvm2 a--  <1.80t    0 
  /dev/md126 vg_tmp  lvm2 a--  <9.99g    0 
  /dev/md127 vg_swap lvm2 a--  <9.99g    0 
➜  ~
```

thanks

Comment: If you are still interested: To better see how much space you have, please add the output of `vgs` and `pvs` to the question.

Comment: Hi @berndbausch . I have added it.